# Deselecting features when zooming to certain zoom-level in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, geojson, zoom

I am currently setting up a Leaflet map. I have a GeoJSON-layer and I filter it at a certain Zoom-level. So when I zoom out all of Europe is showing and when the Zoom-level is greater than 10 some tiles of a city appear and the rest of Europe is gone. So far so good.
But now comes the tricky part. When I click on a country at the beginning, the country highlights as it should. And when I zoom in closer to make the selected country disappear and instead show the tiles of the city, it rememberes that I have clicked the country at the beginning. So when I click on a tile the bounding box of the country is bigger than the tile and so it zooms out to the previous selected country.

How can I force Leaflet to forget that I have selected a country and only remember the selected tiles at a zoom-level greater than 10?

```
            var europe = L.geoJson(hamburgData, {
                filter: function(feature, layer) {
                    if (feature.properties.id_main > 999999) {
                        return feature.properties.id_main;
                    }
                },
                style: stylelayer.standard,
                onEachFeature: onEachFeature
            }).addTo(map)

            var hamburgData = L.geoJson(hamburgData, {
                filter: function(feature, layer) {
                    if (feature.properties.id_main < 999999) {
                        return feature.properties.id_main;
                    }
                },
                style: stylelayer.standard,
                onEachFeature: onEachFeature
            })

            map.on('zoomend',
                function() {
                    if (map.getZoom() < 10) {
                        map.removeLayer(hamburgData)
                        map.addLayer(europe);
                    }


                    if (map.getZoom() > 10) {
                        map.removeLayer(europe)
                        map.addLayer(hamburgData)

                    }
                }
            );

            function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {

                layer.on({
                    mouseover: highlightFeature,
                    mouseout: resetHighlight,
                    click: zoomToFeature
                });

            }
  function highlightFeature(e) {
                var layer = e.target;
                layer.setStyle(stylelayer.highlight);

            }

            function resetHighlight(e) {
                var layer = e.target;
                var feature = e.target.feature;
                if (checkExistsLayers(feature)) {
                    setStyleLayer(layer, stylelayer.highlight)
                } else {
                    setStyleLayer(layer, stylelayer.standard)
                }
                

            }

            var featuresSelected = []

            function zoomToFeature(e) {

                var layer = e.target;
                var feature = e.target.feature;

                if (checkExistsLayers(feature)) {
                    removerlayers(feature, setStyleLayer, layer, stylelayer.standard)
                    removeBounds(layer)

                } else {
                    addLayers(feature, setStyleLayer, layer, stylelayer.highlight)
                    addBounds(layer)
                }
                map.fitBounds(arrayBounds);
                detailsselected.update(featuresSelected)

            }

            function selectTypeaheadFeature(layer) {
                var layer = layer;
                var feature = layer.feature;

                if (checkExistsLayers(feature)) {
                    removerlayers(feature, setStyleLayer, layer, stylelayer.standard)

                    removeBounds(layer)

                } else {
                    addLayers(feature, setStyleLayer, layer, stylelayer.highlight)
                    addBounds(layer)
                }
                map.fitBounds(arrayBounds.length != 0 ? arrayBounds : initbounds)
                detailsselected.update(featuresSelected)
            }

            
            function addBounds(layer) {
                arrayBounds.push(layer.getBounds())
            }


            function removeBounds(layer) {
                arrayBounds = arrayBounds.filter(bounds => bounds != layer.getBounds())
            }

            function setStyleLayer(layer, styleSelected) {
                layer.setStyle(styleSelected)
            }

            function removerlayers(feature, callback) {
                featuresSelected = featuresSelected.filter(obj => obj.id_main != feature.properties.id_main)
                callback(arguments[2], arguments[3])
            }

            function addLayers(feature, callback) {
                featuresSelected.push({
                    id_main: feature.properties.id_main,
                    feature: feature
                })
                callback(arguments[2], arguments[3])
            }




            function checkExistsLayers(feature) {
                var result = false
                for (var i = 0; i < featuresSelected.length; i++) {
                    if (featuresSelected[i].id_main == feature.properties.id_main) {
                        result = true;
                        break;
                    }

                };
                return result
            }

            //show info layers

            var info = L.control({
                position: 'topleft'
            });

            info.onAdd = function(map) {
                this._div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info');
                this.update();
                return this._div;
            };
```

[image: this is where the map starts]

[image: now I select a country and it automatically zoomes to the country]

[image: now I zoom even further and the tiles of a city appear. If I click on a tile it jumpes back]

Comment: Please [edit](https://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/432687/edit) your question and add code for `highlightFeature`, `resetHighlight` and `zoomToFeature` functions. Without those functions it's impossible to guess what you mean by "it remembers that I have clicked".

Comment: Hi @TomazicM 
Thank you very much for your response.

I added some more code-snippets. Does this help you?


Thank you so much in advance for your help!

Comment: You published a bunch of complex code without explanation of it's logic, so reader has mentally go through it and try to guess the logic. Without actual data to try it it's too much to ask of a reader. Post working code to JSFiddle or similar site so it can be debugged.